# Python - разделить строку на слова и записать их в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно создать программу, которая получит какую то строку, например "слово1 слово2 слово3 слово4", затем их распределит вот так:

```
слово1
слово2
слово3
слово4
```

и после этого так же запишет их в текстовый файл.

Я уже пытался что то написать, и почти получилось. Когда я ввожу слова, они распределяются правильно, но записываются только в одну строку, что я делаю не так?

```
for word in input().split():
print(word)
file = open("words.txt", "a")
file.write(word)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас вероятно проблемы с отступами. Дальше, не хорошо постоянно открывать и закрывать файл в цикле:

```
with open("words.txt", "a") as file:
    for word in input().split():
        print(word)
        file.write(word + "\n")
```

Конструкция `with` позволяет вам (кроме других преимуществ) забыть о закрытии файла т.к. он закроется автоматически после выхода из этой конструкции.

Дальше, как вы можете видеть из моего кода, вам нужно вручную добавить знак перехода на новую строку `"\n"` потому что метод `.write()` не делает это автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! <3

Comment: @FruthyzGang, не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не записываете символ перевода строки `\n`.

Когда Вы печатаете слова с помощью функции `print`, символ перевода строки добавляется автоматически в самый конец, потому что он является стандартным значением параметра `end`.

Но запись в файл не добавляет этот символ автоматически, поэтому Вам необходимо добавить его вручную:

```py
file.write(word + '\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! <3

Answer (score 0):

Можно выводить текст в файл с помощью `print`, результат будет точно такой же как при выводе на экран (переносы строк будут добавлены автоматически):

```
print(word, file=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще добавить цикл `while`

```
a = True
while a:
    f = 'test-1'
    with open(f, 'a') as file:
        for a in input().split():
            file.write(a + '\n')
```